# parquet version used to write a file

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, parquet

is there a way to find out what parquet version was used to write a parquet file in HDFS?
I'm trying to see if various files were written using the same parquet version or different versions.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ hadoop jar parquet-tools-1.9.0.jar meta my-parquet-file.parquet |grep "parquet-mr version"

creator:                     parquet-mr version 1.8.1 (build 4aba4dae7bb0d4edbcf7923ae1339f28fd3f7fcf)
```

Comment: Weird, I only see the build hash, so I had to go to the https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/releases and match the first 7 characters of the hash to know the version. Anyway, it works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Other option using parquet-tools

```
parquet-tools meta --debug file.parquet
```